# Uniform norm of eigenfunctions of laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\{\phi_i\}$ the sequence of the eigenfunctions of laplacian operator on a domain $\Omega$, that is, considering $\{\lambda_i\}$ the respective eigenvalues, we have
$$
\int \nabla \phi_{i} \cdot \nabla \psi = \lambda \int \phi_{i} \psi, \forall \psi \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega).
$$ Define the space
$$
V=\text{span}\{\phi_1,..., \phi_k  \}.
$$
Is it true that the uniform norm is well definido on $V$? That is,
$$
||u||_{\infty} = \sup_{\Omega}{|u(x)|} < \infty, \forall u \in V?
$$

**The context**: My professor said that the norm $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ and $||\cdot||_{H^{1}_{0}}$ are equivalent in $V$ because it has finite dimension. I couldn't use any Sobolev embedding theorem to conclude that $H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ is contained in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ because all I know its $H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ is continuously embedded in $L^{q}(\Omega)$ for all $q \in [1, 2^*]$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I just added some new information.

Comment: Weak solutions to $-\Delta u=f$ are in $L^\infty$ for $f\in L^p$ with $p>d/2$,  where $\Omega\subset R^d$, see Stampacchia, Guido
Le problème de Dirichlet pour les équations elliptiques du second ordre à coefficients discontinus. (French)
Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble) 15 (1965), fasc. 1, 189–258.

Comment: Thank you very much!